# Has anyone faced this : MongoError: unknown top level operator: $lt

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Facing this from past 2 days `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $lt`. I see a few questions posted but they do not answer directly why this occurs.

Comment: Please post the query you are trying to execute.

Comment: Also see this: [Minmal-Reproducible-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).